# mute switch + do not disturb shortcut?

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app, do-not-disturb

looked everywhere, but I couldn't find a way to make a **shortcut** for my silent switch to automatically put on *do not disturb* when on. Any ideas or tricks ? I'm new to the app, but just want a quick solution.

Comment: Which app are you referring to?

Comment: Siri shortcuts app, are there any other suggestions ?